# Calculating polygon area inside another polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, field-calculator, area

Is it possible to calculate the area of colorful polygons (yellow, yellowish/reddish and red) inside another shapefile (purple outline, also polygons) in QGIS.

For example the polygon that is marked with red line: i'd like to know how much there is yellow, red etc inside the polygon with purple colored outline (area).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the following steps:

1. Select the target polygon (purple color)
2. Use intersect tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Intersect`
3. In the `Input vector`, choose the colorful polygon layer, and choose the purple layer in the `intersect layer field`
4. Check Use only selected, as you can see below:

[image]

5. Save the output intersected layer
6. Start editing of the output layer and add new field in the attribute table, and give it a name Area, and in the expression, write `$Area`, and press on `Update All` to update Area field. Save edits.

   Make sure that both layers have the same projection.